# backbone.js unable to render li inside ul

Tags: backbone.js

Am new to backbone.js and having problem with the view render part. please find the code below , am unable to print li inside the ul.Html part is given below

```
<ul id="listview"></ul>
<script type="text/template" id="item">
  <li><%= author %></li>
</script>
```

and the js part

```
var book = Backbone.Model.extend();
var cols = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:book,
    url:"http://localhost/bbq/books.php"
});

var col  = new cols();
var view = Backbone.View.extend({

 el:'#listview',
 initialize:function () {
     _.bindAll(this, "render"); 
     this.model.fetch({
        success:this.render  
    });
 }, 

 render: function () {
      _.each(this.model.models, function (mode) {
          $(this.el).append( new listUsers({model:mode}).render.el );
     },this);
     return this;
 }

});

var listUsers = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: _.template($('#item').html()),
   render:function () {  
     $( this.el ).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );  
     return this;
   }
});
var vieb = new view({ model : col });
```

Comment: I have been seeing this `$(this.el).append( new listUsers({model:mode}).render.el` pattern in so many questions... may I know from where you're learning this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you are not invoking the `render` method of child views.

Change

```
$(this.el).append( new listUsers({model:mode}).render.el
```

to

```
$(this.el).append( new listUsers({model:mode}).render().el
```

Your code can be better written as follows:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Book,
  url: "http://localhost/bbq/books.php"
});
var ListUsers = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#item').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

var Booksview = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#listview',
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: this.render
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
      this.$el.append(new ListUsers({
        model: model
      }).el);
    }, this);
    return this;
  }
});

var books = new Books();
var view = new Booksview({
  collection: books
});
```